# Angular subscribe function not firing on http 404 error

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I've been struggling with some angular code. The thing is, I make a request with angular http client to `http://myapi.com/something/1`. If the api does not find something with id `1` then it returns a 404 error. Thats fine. But, for some reason, when I subscribe to the http call and get the 404 error, the `error` function of the subscribe is not firing:

```js
certificatesService
      .getDetail(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: (error) => console.log ('error', error) // never reaches this point
      });
```

I've already tried with catchError inside pipe and all sort of things. Nothing happens and don't know what else can I try.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
certificatesService
      .getDetail(id)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        (error) => console.log ('error', error) 
      );
```